# WARN: Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit

Tags: circuit, error, log

Not exactly what to however I have recently moved to windows 10 and I can no longer use tor. When ever I try to connect, it never moves past 85% and spams `04/07/17 15:52:23 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit.`  until I cancel it. I will paste the log below:

```
04/07/17 15:52:21 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
04/07/17 15:52:21 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
04/07/17 15:52:21 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
04/07/17 15:52:21 PM.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
04/07/17 15:52:21 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network 
04/07/17 15:52:21 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
04/07/17 15:52:21 PM.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
04/07/17 15:52:22 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
04/07/17 15:52:23 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
04/07/17 15:52:24 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
04/07/17 15:52:25 PM.600 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
04/07/17 15:52:26 PM.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
04/07/17 15:52:26 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
04/07/17 15:52:26 PM.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
04/07/17 15:52:26 PM.600 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

The log always looks like this but the amount of [WARN] vary depending on how long I run it for. It has not crashed or anything like that. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What changes have you made from the default Tor Browser configuration?

Comment: I have made no changes

Comment: It's failing to find a suitable guard to build a circuit, you haven't configured any restrictions on reachable addresses, ports or countries, etc? Can you provide your torrc file?

Comment: Not sure how to do that and I use goodles DNS but that's about all I can think of

Comment: Tor doesn't use DNS, so it shouldn't be an issue. The torrc is a text file located under `Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc` inside your Tor Browser folder.

Comment: I've had the same problem and fixed it by manually correcting my time zone, then re-enabling the automatic timezone-stuff. I guess tor panics when this doesn't add up. I just wanted to thank the person that suggested that, but new accounts cannot reply apparently, so I hope the rep is sufficient when it shows up!

Answer (score 4):

Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly.
Please sync your time with an [NTP (Network Time Protocol)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTP) server.

***Debian family***
On Debian based machines use package [`ntpdate`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/ntpdate).

```
sudo ntpdate -v pool.ntp.org
```

***Windows***

1. Win+R
2. Type *cmd.exe*
3. Type following:

   ```
   w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:pool.ntp.org  
   w32tm /config /update
   ```
4. Done!